# Use fallback content of slot only if condition is met

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-slot

I would like to know if there is a way to do what I'm trying to describe below:

Let's suppose we have a component with a slot, and a fallback content has been defined.

When using this component elsewhere, I would like to have the following behavior:

```html
<TheComponent>
  <template v-slot:name="{ data }">
    <fallback v-if="condition(data)"/>
  </template>
</TheComponent>
```

I suppose the `fallback` tag (or similar) does not exists (at least, I didn't find it...). So I suppose I'm thinking the wrong way, but I can't find a solution to my problem.

The thing is that I can't alter the `TheComponent` as it is provided by an external library, and I don't want to re-create the content.

If it can help, in fact, I'm trying to hide the expand button to prevent to expand a row in a Vuetify `data-table`, depending on if the row has something to show or not in it's expanded part. So I would like to write something that behave like:

```html
<v-data-table :items="items" show-expand ...>
  <template v-slot:item.data-table-expand="{ item }">
    <!-- Here I want the default behavior only if my item respects some condition -->
    <fallback v-if="condition(item)"/>
    <!-- Otherwise, I don't want to display the button that expands the row -->
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10):

After quite a lot of "googling" I don't think its possible. IMHO your best bet is to replicate the default slot content Vuetify generates and put it under your own condition (`v-if="item.description"` in my example):

```html
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="people" show-expand>
      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item, headers }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">{{ item.description }}</td>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.data-table-expand="{ item, isExpanded, expand }">
        <v-icon
          v-if="item.description"
          :class="['v-data-table__expand-icon', { 'v-data-table__expand-icon--active': isExpanded }]"
          @click.stop="expand(!isExpanded)"
        >$expand</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

I understand this solution is brittle and can break anytime Vuetify change something but i don't think there is better solution now...

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-fallback-content-of-slot-only-if-condition-is-met-68u5w)

Comment: Really great code! Thank you so much, it helped a lot. | It would be fine to put a similar nice (animated) button to the header (in the same column, where the row-expanders are) with the role of "Expand all" and "Collapse all", like here: codepen.io/snize/pen/GRggXwp

Comment: @szabozoltan You can do that easily with `header.data-table-expand` slot. See my updated example...

Comment: Fantastic! This code is a gold mine... Thanks really!